# Как обновить версию python через Anaconda offline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, offline

Необходимо обновить python до последней версии, компьютер не подключен к интернету. Не пойму как можно это сделать...Знаю что можно устанавливать библиотеки оффлайн предварительно скачав их. Но у python exe файл, как его правильно установить?

Comment: да просто скачайте exe нужной версии и запустите его.

Comment: дак я скачал, а anaconda распознает нормально такую установку? она же вроде сама как-то ставит...